# working on TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

hey guys,
i am using TFS 2010, i have uploaded content on TFS server, but i dont have any clue about how to download the content from TFS server to local system so that i can check out and check in once i have done editing

Any one know how to do that.. please reply...

i need a step for the same.

Thanks and Regards
Abbas Electricwala

Comment: This isn't a question - it's a request for tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a local Workspace (if there isn't one already) and then map your project to a local working directory. From Step 1 of this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx):

> You can create a workspace mapping in one of two ways:
>
> ```
> * Set the workspace mapping explicitly
> * Perform a Get operation on your team project.
> ```
>
> To set a workspace mapping explicitly
>
> 1. In Visual Studio, on the File menu, point to Source Control and then
>      click Workspaces.
> 2. In the Manage Workspaces dialog box, select your computer name and
>      then click Edit.
> 3. In the Edit Workspace dialog box, in the Working folders list,
>      click Click here to enter a new
>      working folder.
> 4. Click the ellipsis (…) button, select your team project (for example
>      MyTeamProject1), and then click OK.
> 5. Click the local folder cell to display another ellipsis button.
> 6. Click the ellipsis button beneath Local Folder and then browse
>      to and select the local folder on your
>      development computer where you want to
>      locate your team project; for example,
>      C:\DevProjects\MyTeamProject1.
> 7. Click OK twice to close the Edit Workspace dialog box.
> 8. Click OK in response to the Microsoft Visual Studio message box
>      that informs you than one or more
>      working folders have changed.
> 9. Click Close to close the Manage Workspaces dialog box.
>
> To perform a Get operation on your
>   team project
>
> 1. In Team Explorer, expand your team project node; for example,
>      MyTeamProject1.
> 2. Double-click Source Control beneath your team project.
> 3. In Source Control Explorer, right-click the root folder
>      MyTeamProject1 and then click Get
>      Latest Version.
> 4. In the Browse For Folder dialog box, select your local path (for
>      example,
>      C:\DevProjects\MyTeamProject1) and
>      then click OK. This maps the team
>      project root folder within TFS to a
>      local path on your computer.